# Open Source Disk Manager / Partitioning Tool for Windows

Tags: open-source, hard-disk, utility

Windows Disk Manager has to be one of the most limited disk manager / partitioning tools that I've ever used, and I've come across plenty of other disk partitioning tools for Windows, but they've all been closed source.

Can anybody recommend a good, open source disk manager for Windows?

Comment: Welcome. Open source, or free (no cost)? For the latter, use the [tag:gratis] tag - and expect more answers.

Comment: What are you try to archive that Disk Manager cannot give you?

Comment: Did you try [Paragon Partition Manager Community](https://www.paragon-software.com/free/pm-express/#)? You can create live disk with it.

Answer (score 0):

[gparted](https://gparted.org/) is a linux based boot disk/boot flash program that few would consider limited.

from the site:

Perform actions with partitions such as:

```
create or delete
resize or move
check
label
set new UUID
copy and paste
```

Manipulate file systems such as:

```
btrfs
ext2 / ext3 / ext4
fat16 / fat32
hfs / hfs+
linux-swap
lvm2 pv
nilfs2
ntfs
reiserfs / reiser4
udf
ufs
xfs
```

I have used the program a number of times with zero problems. Perhaps the greatest nuisance is to occasionally have to disable the secure boot feature of some computers.

Comment: Unfortunately, it seems like it has to be run from a USB drive or a CD in windows, which is extremely inconvenient for me.

Comment: One consideration when performing partition edits is that a mounted drive cannot be safely modified. By booting to a DVD or USB drive, the drives in question are not mounted, facilitating the process. Good luck with your search.

Comment: Gparted on USB is my go-to tool for this. Great suggestion!

Comment: Gparted is not available for Windows.

Comment: Gparted is a boot system, and works independently of the operating system installed.

Comment: @fred_dot_u that's completely wrong. gparted is simply a Linux application, and the fact that someone made a bootable drive that has gparted built-in doesn't change that, it's still just an application and not a boot system